# LAMP Stack Location

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, lamp

I have installed the LAMP stack on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using the tasksel command. 
I checked - it works. But I cant find the location of the installaton, 
I worked with WAMP - there you have a separate folder for Apache, for PHP and for mysql. Now I cant even find where to put the documents I create.

Which folder is used to contain my web projects?

How to start MySQL console and where to look for its installation directory?

Which directories are PHP and Apache installed in?

how to erase LAMP stack?

I found out that some of the parts of the stack are installed in the root/var and root/etc directories?

How can I install the whole LAMP stack in /home?

Comment: Please split this off into separate questions, some of these have been asked and answered already.

Answer (score 5):

According to **my** LAMP server ...

- The PHP files are located in `/var/www/`.
- Apache is located in `/etc/init.d/apache2`.
- To open the MySQL terminal, just type `mysql -u root -p` in the command line. Changing password:

  > `mysqladmin -u root password new-password`
- My PHP runs on `/etc/php5/`, but it depends on your version, you can search for the `php.ini` file using these commands:

  `cd /`
  `find ./ -iname php.ini`

I don't know if there is a way *(even if it's possible)* to change the installation location to your home directory.